# Minimum distance between latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: blackberry

How do I calculate the distance between two coordinates in Google map on BlackBerry?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use Google map for getting distance of two cities.
All you need to have is getting latitude and longitude of two cities.
This is how I did.
Coordinates is native Blackberry class

```
Coordinates ahmedabad=new Coordinates(23.03333,72.61667, Float.NaN);
Coordinates delhi=new Coordinates(28.66667,77.21667, Float.NaN);

dist=ahmedabad.distance(delhi);
```

Comment: ravi are u dere?? Whats ur email id.I want to ask some more questions to you.....Can u help me??

Comment: If you have more questions, just ask them one at a time, like you asked us your minimum distance question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following code:

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic

ahmedabad = (23.03333,72.61667)
delhi = (28.66667,77.21667)

print(geodesic(origin, dest).meters)
print(geodesic(origin, dest).kilometers)
print(geodesic(origin, dest).miles)
```

Comment: As this is an older post. Please include software versions to which this answer applies to. (End of Review).